# Pandas read excel and skip cells with strikethrough

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I have to process some `xlsx` received from external source. Is there a more straightforward way to load a `xlsx` in `pandas` while also skipping rows with strikethrough?

Currently I have to do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd, openpyxl

working_file = r"something.xlsx"

working_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(working_file, data_only=True)

working_sheet = working_wb.active

empty = []

for row in working_sheet.iter_rows("B", row_offset=3):
    for cell in row:
        if cell.font.strike is True:
            p_id = working_sheet.cell(row=cell.row, column=37).value
            empty.append(p_id)

df = pd.read_excel(working_file, skiprows=3)
df = df[~df["ID"].isin(empty)]
...
```

Which works but only by going through every excel sheet twice.

Comment: how does the dataframe appear when you read in the file - the rows with the strikethrough, do they look different? mangled? or plain numbers like the rest? a picture or some reproducible example could help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up subclassing `pd.ExcelFile` and `_OpenpyxlReader`. It was easier than I thought :)

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.excel._openpyxl import _OpenpyxlReader
from pandas._typing import Scalar
from typing import List
from pandas.io.excel._odfreader import _ODFReader
from pandas.io.excel._xlrd import _XlrdReader

class CustomReader(_OpenpyxlReader):
    def get_sheet_data(self, sheet, convert_float: bool) -> List[List[Scalar]]:
        data = []
        for row in sheet.rows:
            first = row[1] # I need the strikethrough check on this cell only
            if first.value is not None and first.font.strike: continue
            else:
                data.append([self._convert_cell(cell, convert_float) for cell in row])
        return data

class CustomExcelFile(pd.ExcelFile):

    _engines = {"xlrd": _XlrdReader, "openpyxl": CustomReader, "odf": _ODFReader}
```

With the custom classes set, now just pass the files like a normal `ExcelFile`, specify the engine to `openpyxl` and voila! Rows with strikethrough cells are gone.

```
excel = CustomExcelFile(r"excel_file_name.xlsx", engine="openpyxl")

df = excel.parse()

print (df)
```

Comment: I have used this solution for a while now. However, after a recent update of several libraries, it has stopped working.
I receive:
`TypeError: CustomReader.get_sheet_data() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`
I have tried troubleshooting this, but I'm completely lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Some point past pandas 1.4.1, this solution breaks (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237797/subclassing-pandas-and-openpyxl-to-read-excel-and-skip-cells-with-strikethrough).

Answer (score 3):

Updating @Henry-Yik 's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59854993/22122301) with the following versions:

- Python 3.11.2
- pandas 2.0.0
- openpyxl 3.1.2

The updated solution accomplishes the following:

- Subclassing the pandas OpenpyxlReader class (pandas renamed the _OpenpyxlReader class to OpenpyxlReader)
- Copying the pandas function get_sheet_data from pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py and adding several lines of code for the strikethrough detection
- Subclassing pd.ExcelFile

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.excel._openpyxl import OpenpyxlReader
from pandas._typing import Scalar
from typing import List

# get_sheet_data code copied from <Python base directory>/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py
class CustomReader(OpenpyxlReader):
    def get_sheet_data(
        self, sheet, file_rows_needed: int | None = None
    ) -> list[list[Scalar]]:
        if self.book.read_only:
            sheet.reset_dimensions()

        data: list[list[Scalar]] = []
        last_row_with_data = -1
        for row_number, row in enumerate(sheet.rows):
            
            #########################################################
            # Custom code to not read row if row[1] item is strikethrough
            if len(row) > 1:
                first = row[1]
                if first.value is not None and first.font.strike:
                    continue
            #########################################################
            
            converted_row = [self._convert_cell(cell) for cell in row]
            while converted_row and converted_row[-1] == "":
                # trim trailing empty elements
                converted_row.pop()
            if converted_row:
                last_row_with_data = row_number
            data.append(converted_row)
            if file_rows_needed is not None and len(data) >= file_rows_needed:
                break

        # Trim trailing empty rows
        data = data[: last_row_with_data + 1]

        if len(data) > 0:
            # extend rows to max width
            max_width = max(len(data_row) for data_row in data)
            if min(len(data_row) for data_row in data) < max_width:
                empty_cell: list[Scalar] = [""]
                data = [
                    data_row + (max_width - len(data_row)) * empty_cell
                    for data_row in data
                ]

        return data

class CustomExcelFile(pd.ExcelFile):

    _engines = {"openpyxl": CustomReader,}
```

As before, just use the custom class like:

```py
    excel = CustomExcelFile('file.xlsx', engine="openpyxl")
    
    # header=2 is just example of adding parse options
    df = excel.parse(header=2)
    print (df)
```

Comment: I will recieve this error for any sheet read with that code: ```Cell In[38], line 21, in CustomReader.get_sheet_data(self, sheet, file_rows_needed)
     19 if len(row) > 1:
     20     first = row[1]
---> 21     if first.font.strike:
     22         continue
     23 #########################################################            

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strike'```

Comment: @kaschmir I modified the code to the line 'if first.value is not None and first.font.strike:' similar to the original answer to handle cases where the object is None

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would not use Pandas. Just use openpyxl, work from the **end** of the worksheet and delete rows accordingly. Working backwards from the end of the worksheet means you don't suffer with side-effects when deleting rows.

Comment: Unfortunately there are a lot of pandas operation which I didn’t include since it is irrelevant to the question. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: You can still pass things into a dataframe once you've tidied up the rows. This will then be easier and more reliable than your current approach.

Comment: I ended up sub-classing `pd.ExcelFile` to skip the strikethrough cells through `openpyxl`.