# Subclassing Pandas and Openpyxl to read excel and skip cells with "strikethrough"

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

**The Problem at hand:**
I want to parse and concatenate hundreds of excel tables. However, many of these have entries that are formatted with [strikethrough](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/where-is-the-font-strikethrough-option-e6df3b9d-cea6-4406-9271-5a5a52d66738). **I need to skip these entries.**
Per request, this is a minimal [example file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/qw8sia2eh8ml8fs/example_file.xlsx/file), and a picture of the example table (values are randomized and may differ in the file):
[image]

**The solution**:
As @Alka has pointed out below, the code works with pandas=1.4.1. - my current solution is a separate conda environment with a frozen pandas version.
Of course, I'd still be happy about any suggestions on how to make this run with up-to-date libraries.

**The code**
I have used [the solution provided by @Henry Yik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59525171/pandas-read-excel-and-skip-cells-with-strikethrough) for longer than a year.
Taken from the original stackoverflow-thread linked above:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.excel._openpyxl import _OpenpyxlReader
from pandas._typing import Scalar
from typing import List
from pandas.io.excel._odfreader import _ODFReader
from pandas.io.excel._xlrd import _XlrdReader

class CustomReader(_OpenpyxlReader):
    def get_sheet_data(self, sheet, convert_float: bool) -> List[List[Scalar]]:
        data = []
        for row in sheet.rows:
            first = row[1] # I need the strikethrough check on this cell only
            if first.value is not None and first.font.strike: continue
            else:
                data.append([self._convert_cell(cell, convert_float) for cell in row])
        return data

class CustomExcelFile(pd.ExcelFile):

    _engines = {"xlrd": _XlrdReader, "openpyxl": CustomReader, "odf": _ODFReader}
```

Unfortunately, it broke with some library updates early October. I was not able to get it to run again.
I would be really happy to solve this. I use this solution in several workflows.
I couldn't figure out how to solve the issue. I tried fiddling around with the CustomReader - class, to no avail. Neither was I sucessful with reinstating an older environments.yml.

```
excel = CustomExcelFile(r"excel_file_name.xlsx", engine="openpyxl")
df = excel.parse()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [12], line 17
     15     file.decrypt(decrypted)   
     16     excel = CustomExcelFile(decrypted, engine = "openpyxl")
---> 17     data = excel.parse(usecols="A:M", index = 0, header = 0)


File /home/dev/anaconda3/envs/lwo_datasci/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py:1734, in ExcelFile.parse(self, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, **kwds)
   1700 def parse(
   1701     self,
   1702     sheet_name: str | int | list[int] | list[str] | None = 0,
   (...)
   1721     **kwds,
   1722 ) -> DataFrame | dict[str, DataFrame] | dict[int, DataFrame]:
   1723     """
   1724     Parse specified sheet(s) into a DataFrame.
   1725 
   (...)
   1732         DataFrame from the passed in Excel file.
   1733     """
-> 1734     return self._reader.parse(
   1735         sheet_name=sheet_name,
   1736         header=header,
   1737         names=names,
   1738         index_col=index_col,
   1739         usecols=usecols,
   1740         squeeze=squeeze,
   1741         converters=converters,
   1742         true_values=true_values,
   1743         false_values=false_values,
   1744         skiprows=skiprows,
   1745         nrows=nrows,
   1746         na_values=na_values,
   1747         parse_dates=parse_dates,
   1748         date_parser=date_parser,
   1749         thousands=thousands,
   1750         comment=comment,
   1751         skipfooter=skipfooter,
   1752         convert_float=convert_float,
   1753         mangle_dupe_cols=mangle_dupe_cols,
   1754         **kwds,
   1755     )

File /home/dev/anaconda3/envs/lwo_datasci/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py:765, in BaseExcelReader.parse(self, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, decimal, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, **kwds)
    762     sheet = self.get_sheet_by_index(asheetname)
    764 file_rows_needed = self._calc_rows(header, index_col, skiprows, nrows)
--> 765 data = self.get_sheet_data(sheet, convert_float, file_rows_needed)
    766 if hasattr(sheet, "close"):
    767     # pyxlsb opens two TemporaryFiles
    768     sheet.close()

TypeError: CustomReader.get_sheet_data() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
> TypeError: CustomReader.get_sheet_data() takes 3 positional arguments
> but 4 were given
```

Comment: Kindly provide the sample excel file

Comment: @sammywemmy I have linked an example file, added a link to an explanation of the strikethrough format, and a picture of the example table.  
Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @Kaschmir What versions of `pandas` and `openpyxl` are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be related to versions of libraries you are using.
I've tried your code with the following versions and it worked (but I had to change the way the engines are imported from pandas):

- `pandas==1.4.1`
- `openpyxl==3.0.10`

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.excel._openpyxl import OpenpyxlReader
from pandas._typing import Scalar
from typing import List
from pandas.io.excel._odfreader import ODFReader
from pandas.io.excel._xlrd import XlrdReader

class CustomReader(OpenpyxlReader):
    def get_sheet_data(self, sheet, convert_float: bool) -> List[List[Scalar]]:
        data = []
        for row in sheet.rows:
            first = row[1] # I need the strikethrough check on this cell only
            if first.value is not None and first.font.strike: continue
            else:
                data.append([self._convert_cell(cell, convert_float) for cell in row])
        return data


class CustomExcelFile(pd.ExcelFile):

    _engines = {"xlrd": XlrdReader, "openpyxl": CustomReader, "odf": ODFReader}
```

And then :

```py
excel = CustomExcelFile("example_file.xlsx", engine="openpyxl")
df = excel.parse()
df
```

[image: example_output]

Comment: @Kaschmir, this solution should suffice, right?

Comment: Hey, thanks for this quick answer. I will test this soon and provide feedback.

Comment: I set up another conda environment with pandas = 1.4.1.
Indeed, that solved the issue. It's a bit annoying, since I now have to switch environments constantly, but hey, at least it works again.
Thank you!